急にjuliaが使えなくなった
急にjuliaが使えなくなりました。
OSはwindows 11です。
juliaはMSストアからインストールしたものだったと思います。
juliaのバージョンは今juliaが動かないのでどうやって調べたらいいかわからないです。
cygwinでjulia と打つと以下のようなエラーになります。
/cygdrive/c/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/julia: Permission denied
このフォルダへ行ってchmodしようとしても
$ chmod 777 julia.exe
chmod: changing permissions of 'julia.exe': Permission denied
となってしまいます。
きっかけとしてはwindows updateか、ストレージがいっぱいになってきたので要らなさそうなファイルを消して回ったことくらいしか思い当たらないですがどうしたらいいでしょうか？

「juliaはMSストアからインストールしたものだったと思います。」アプリ一覧にはでで来ないんでしょうか？

この辺の記事が参考になるかもしれませんね。"Permission Denied" using cygwin in Windows, chmod cannot change group permission on Cygwin, cygwin "Permission denied"

cygwinからは使えないけどコマンドプロンプトからは使えるようです。なぜ？

とりあえずコマンドプロンプトで急場をしのぎます。
